# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NotMee' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a table and a column of `varchar` data type, however when I insert text after I inserted some numbers the insert fail.

```
CREATE TABLE TestInfo
(
    ROWID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    TEST1 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)

-- (note that these are two varchar columns)
INSERT INTO TestInfo (TEST1, NAME)
VALUES (12354, 'Gerrit'),
       (44586, 'SomeOtherguy'),
       ('123', 'Test'),
       ('5555', 'TEST'),
       ('NotMee', 'TEST2') --Why would it want to convert that to an `INT` when the column clearly gets created as a `VARCHAR`?
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around the first two integers like this:

```
INSERT INTO TestInfo
(TEST1, NAME)-- (note that these are two Varchar Columns)
 VALUES ('12354', 'Gerrit'),
     ('44586', 'SomeOtherguy'),
       ('123', 'Test'),
       ('5555', 'TEST'),
       ('NotMee', 'TEST2')
```

I will look through the documentation, but it looks like SQL has inferred that the first column is an integer based on the first two values which obviously failed for 'NotMee' but not for the other values.